# Change product variation prices via a hook in WooCommerce 3.3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I´m using hooks for customizing variable product prices.

However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806249/change-product-prices-via-a-hook-in-woocommerce-3/45807054#45807054) does not seem to be working for Woocommerce 3.3.5.

I use following (from the previous post) on my `functions.php` file:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_price', 'custom_variation_price', 99, 3 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price', 'custom_variation_price', 99, 3 );
function custom_variation_price( $price, $variation, $product ) {
    // Delete product cached price  (if needed)
wc_delete_product_transients($variation->get_id());

return $price * 3; // X2 for testing
}
```

On product page the price range for product variations shows correct prices (original price*3) but when I select options, price shown for variation is unfiltered. Am I missing something here?

---

**EDIT:** I had a slightly different price calculation for simple products and for product variations. I ended up with 3 functions:

```php
// Simple
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );

// Variable
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'custom_price_2', 99, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'custom_price_2' , 99, 2 );

// Variations (of a variable product)
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_price', 'custom_variation_price', 99, 3 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price', 'custom_variation_price', 99, 3 );

function custom_price( $price, $product ) {
    // Delete product cached price  (if needed)
    wc_delete_product_transients($product->get_id());

    return $price * 3; // X3 for testing
}

function custom_price_2( $price, $product ) {
    // Delete product cached price  (if needed)
    wc_delete_product_transients($product->get_id());

    return $price * 2; // X2 for testing
}

function custom_variation_price( $price, $variation, $product ) {
    // Delete product cached price  (if needed)
    wc_delete_product_transients($variation->get_id());


    return $price * 2; // X2 for testing
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [**linked code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806249/change-product-prices-via-a-hook-in-woocommerce-3/45807054#45807054) still work for Woocommerce 3.3.x, see [**this related recent accepted working answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49867865/change-all-product-prices-from-a-specific-product-tag-in-woocommerce-3/49868306#49868306) tested on Woocommerce 3.3.x … Your code is just uncompleted…

You need to use:

```
// Variable
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'custom_price' , 99, 2 );

// Variations (of a variable product)
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_price', 'custom_variation_price', 99, 3 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price', 'custom_variation_price', 99, 3 );

function custom_price( $price, $product ) {
    // Delete product cached price  (if needed)
    wc_delete_product_transients($product->get_id());

    return $price * 3; // X3 for testing
}

function custom_variation_price( $price, $variation, $product ) {
    // Delete product cached price  (if needed)
    wc_delete_product_transients($variation->get_id());

    return $price * 3; // X3 for testing
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had the other part too but must have had some copy-paste error on that.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec is there anyway to do this but only on cart/checkout? My variation price is based on the users inputs on the product page. So I use JS to update price on product page. But am unable to find a function to change the price when it comes to cart/checkout.

Comment: I've posted more details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55636612/display-custom-price-for-variation-product-on-cart-checkout

Answer (score 0):

```
// Simple
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
// Variable
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'custom_price' , 99, 2 );
// Variations (of a variable product)
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_price', 'custom_variation_price', 99, 3 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price', 'custom_variation_price', 99, 3 );

function custom_price( $price, $product ) {
    // Delete product cached price  (if needed)
    wc_delete_product_transients($product->get_id());

    return $price * 3; // X3 for testing
}

function custom_variation_price( $price, $variation, $product ) {
    // Delete product cached price  (if needed)
    wc_delete_product_transients($variation->get_id());

    return $price * 3; // X3 for testing
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).