# WooCommerce filter to change product price only on specific variations

Tags: wordpress, variables, woocommerce, product-variations

I need to increase the products price by 50% only on specific variations (option 4 and option 7). I need it on filter, because products are often import by CSV (changing price, new products, etc). I found some codes on stackoverflow and tryed to merge that, but it doesn't work. It change price for whole product, not only specific variation.

Anyone has idea how to do it?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_price', 'custom_variation_price', 99, 3 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price', 'custom_variation_price', 99, 3 );

function custom_variation_price( $price, $variation, $product ) {
    wc_delete_product_transients($variation->get_id());

$product_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

if (has_term( 'option 4', 'pa_choose_options', $product_id ))
    return $price * 1.5;
    else return $price;
}
```

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943319/change-product-variation-prices-via-a-hook-in-woocommerce-3-3

Comment: Thanks @MartinMirchev, but the problem is with variables filtration. LoicTheAztec code is for all variables.

Comment: Your question is about "only on specific variations ". In this case the price is for each variation so you need to access that variation and from there check what attribute is holding. The example is just to know which hook you need and from there you have access to variation.

Comment: Are you able to help me with this? My programming skills are 5/100. I changed code (edit first post), but now it change price for whole product, not only one variation