# Custom field value to replace product price everywhere in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, price

I have a new custom field named super_sale_price, and I'm trying to use that value for every product, so if this custom field value is exists,then we will show this in every where for that product,

I used this to display that price,

```
function return_custom_price($price, $product) {
    global $post, $blog_id;

     $price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'super_sale_price', true);


    return $price;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2);
```

This changes value in single product page, but once I add this product to cart, there the price shows 0. Please someone tell me why this happening ? Is this is a wrong hook?

Answer (score 0):

The hook that you are using is deprecated, Instead Try this instead:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'display_super_sale_price', 10, 2); 
function display_super_sale_price( $price, $product ) {
    if( $product->get_meta('super_sale_price') );
        $price = $product->get_meta('super_sale_price');

    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

For variable products and product variations, see this answers threads:

- [Change product prices via a hook in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806249/change-product-prices-via-a-hook-in-woocommerce-3/45807054#45807054)
- [Conditional product prices cart issue in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48895844/conditional-product-prices-cart-issue-in-woocommerce-3/48898842#48898842)